# Secure WCF service and Methods

Tags: wcf, security

I have created a WCF service in our Project. There are many methods inside this. Now its opened. That means anyone form outside can create a proxy of our service and could easily use our methods. How to secure this thing. I used BasicHttpbinding and read on the Certificate security. But not able to make secure. Please guide me. Its urgent. I cannot change the basicHttpBindings. So give me a solution to protect my service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe enbale windows authentication is the best solution but it all depends who is allowed and how is not allowed, check the following link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/0e8a4cda-e942-434b-a3d5-8c0ab3502b9b

Comment: Dear Saddam Abu Ghaida, thank you very much for your help. I am using a self hosted service. I am so eager to secure my methods. Please help me. I stuck over here.